# Can I safely remove the Samples folder in Wikitude?

Tags: unity-game-engine, wikitude

I am working on an Augmented Reality project using Wikitude and Unity and I'm fairly new to this. Can I safely remove the Samples folder in the Wikitude assets without breaking the application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have decided to just try it, **you can safely remove the Samples folder** in Wikitude.